# Bash; How to combine multiple files into one file

Tags: bash, scripting

I have multiple file in one directory, I want to combine each file into a single file using Bash. The output need to contain the file name and then list its contents. Example would be

```
$ cat File 1
store

$ cat File 2 
bank

$ cat File 3
car
```

Desired output is in a single file named master

```
$ cat master
File 1
store
File 2 
bank
File 3
car
```

Comment: Have you tried any so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: your example is wrong, you need to quote filenames with spaces in them, even for "cat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for FILE in "File 1" "File 2" "File 3"; do
    echo "$FILE"
    cat "$FILE"
done > master
```

Comment: it there a way I can substitute typing the individual names of each file with a wildcard?

Comment: I have allot more files that needs to be combine than just the three

Comment: all the files that I need to group are in a single directory

Comment: The simplest thing to do is change to the directory, then use `for FILE in *; do`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have asked for is what `cat` is meant for; it's short for `concatenate`, because it concatenates the contents of files together.

But it doesn't inject the filenames into the output. If you want the filenames there, your best bet is probably a loop:

```
for f in "File 1" "File 2" "File 3"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
    cat "$f"
done > master
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
for f in File{1..3} ; do
    echo $f >> master;
    cat $f >> master;
done
```

Comment: the output will not contain the file names

Comment: @neuhaus; I see that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed

```
sed -s '1F' *
```

> '-s'
>   '--separate'
>        By default, 'sed' will consider the files specified on the command
>        line as a single continuous long stream.  This GNU 'sed' extension
>        allows the user to consider them as separate files: range addresses
>        (such as '/abc/,/def/') are not allowed to span several files, line
>        numbers are relative to the start of each file, '$' refers to the
>        last line of each file, and files invoked from the 'R' commands are
>        rewound at the start of each file.
>
> 'F'
>        Print out the file name of the current input file (with a trailing
>        newline).